# How to remove negative values from RasterLayer in R

Tags: r, normalized-difference-water-index

I am processing Landsat 8 images to detect water quality parameters in R. I am using NDWI to masking the images. The raster layer I obtained from NDWI has negative values which I wanted to remove. Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a raster titled LandCover (used the name LC here).
You can assign NA values to your RasterLayer for negative values.

```
 LC[LC < 0] <- NA
```

This will set a lower bound to the values.

Comment: Yes, and the memory safe equivalent would be `calc(LC, fun = function(x){x[x < 0] <- NA; return(x)})`